# Using window as type in d.ts

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I have a function that requires to pass a Node or the window object. My types for this function are:

```
function myFunc(node: Node | window): void;
```

However, when I run this, it complains:

> 'window' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Well I cannot argue with that, but thats what I need. How do I solve this in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `window` is `Window`:

```
function myFunc(node: Node | Window): void {
}

myFunc(window);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQBRjgEwFMAuRAOQMMQB9EB1GMfOAdwEpSA3OGfRAbwCwAKAC+IkWkyRsLRs3YBuREA)